# Неправильное значение интерполяции при больших количествах точек

Tags: python, интерполяция

У меня есть датасет с значениями цены биткоина с 01.01.2021 до 01.04.2021 с шагом в один день. Регулярными выражениями обрабатываю данные, чтоб python мог с ними работать.

```
def data_clean(path):
    crypto = pd.read_csv(path)
    crypto['Цена'] = crypto['Цена'].str.replace(r'\.', '', regex=True).str.replace(r'\,', '.', regex=True)
    crypto['Откр.'] = crypto['Откр.'].str.replace(r'\.', '', regex=True).str.replace(r'\,', '.', regex=True)
    crypto['Макс.'] = crypto['Макс.'].str.replace(r'\.', '', regex=True).str.replace(r'\,', '.', regex=True)
    crypto['Мин.'] = crypto['Мин.'].str.replace(r'\.', '', regex=True).str.replace(r'\,', '.', regex=True)
    crypto['Дата'] = crypto['Дата'].str.replace(r'\.', '-', regex=True)

    crypto['Макс.'] = pd.to_numeric(crypto['Макс.'])
    crypto['Мин.'] = pd.to_numeric(crypto['Мин.'])
    crypto['Цена'] = pd.to_numeric(crypto['Цена'])
    crypto['Откр.'] = pd.to_numeric(crypto['Откр.'])
    return crypto
```

И записываю данный DataFrame в переменную

```
btc = data_clean('./btc-data.csv')
```

Я хочу узнать значение цены биткоина в середине 7 дня.
Для этого я использую интерполяционный полином Лагранжа.

```
def lagranzh(crypto, point):
    answer = 0
    x = [i for i in range(len(crypto['Дата'].tolist()))] #Номер дня(0 - 01.01.2021, 1 - 02.01.2021 и т.д.)
    y = [i for i in crypto['Цена'].tolist()]
    for j in range(len(x)):
        numenator = 1
        denominator = 1
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if i != j:
                numenator *= (point - x[i])
                denominator *= (x[j] - x[i])
        answer += y[j] * numenator / denominator
    return answer
```

При вызове данных принтов

```
print(lagranzh(btc, 7))
print(lagranzh(btc, 7.5))
print(lagranzh(btc, 8))
```

Получаю вот такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методом проб пришел к выводу, что если в функции lagranzh в условиях циклов поставить не len(x), а число < 30, то результат будет близким к верному. Почему из-за большого количества данных интерполяция даёт неправильный результат?

[Датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y1N0eJzQ5PYkDmEC82ydUskNHvfzSmhr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Феномен Рунге. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5 Используйте, например, сплайны.

Comment: На сколько оправдано брать такие большие интервалы, чтобы потом узнавать значение между значениями? Я не слежу за стоимостью BTC, но я понимаю, что падение или рост может происходить в течении 10 -15 мин. По логике вы берете большие промежутки, строите функцию и получаете большую погрешность при резком изменении в течении одного дня. Хотя @AlexAlex дал вам хорошее направление, почему бы не сформулировать в ответ

Comment: @Дмитрий Ну, тут речь о том, что средние значения вообще какие-то нереально большие/маленькие. 10^16 - это очень много, таких колебаний ни на одной бирже не бывает никогда )

Comment: @CrazyElf речь не об ошибке в реализации, а предложение сменить подход. Т.к. ошибка при интерполяции возникает из-за высокой степени полинома. И даже если решение будет найдено (через узлы Чебышева или как было предложено сплайны) все равно ошибка будет ощутимой. Хотя и тут все зависит от условий задачи. ТС?

Comment: На негладких данных интерполяционные полиномы вычислительно неустойчивы. Но проблема вашей задачи не в этом. Ваша задача бессмысленна. Уточнение цены биткойна как интерполяции среднесуточных цен не даёт никаких гарантий точности для сильно волатильного курса. Я не удивлюсь, если среднеквадратичное отклонение для линейной аппроксимации окажется ничуть не хуже полиномиальной.

Comment: Можете данные прислать. Хотя бы сэмпл?